# Kendo Grid column on hide other columns jump to initial width

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, multiple-columns

My example: http://dojo.telerik.com/uhiDU

Problem: All columns have a width of 100px. When initialized the columns adjust their width to the window width in relation to there initial width. (They distribute the window width evenly).
When I hide a column they "jump" to their initial with of 100px and do NOT fill out the whole width of the window (which looks weird).

Screenshot after hiding one column: [image]

How can I make sure the columns adjust to the window size after hiding one?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the width specified for each column, then it will auto fit correctly

Please see the live demo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@amaldevv/AzEhE)

Answer (score 0):

"Hack solution": dojo.telerik.com/aSUbO.

I add the "detailini" function which somehow distributes the columns width evently when hiding / showing them.